# Variable images within a django template

Tags: python, django

I'm new to Django and I'm wondering what is the best way to achieve this.

I hold a large(15K+) amount of images within my static folder, and I wish to present those on a webpage, 3 at a time.

**My attempt:**

I could hardcode the names within my template, like so:

```
<div id="imageholder">
    <img src="{% static "images/im1.jpg" %}" />
    <img src="{% static "images/im2.jpg" %}" />
    <img src="{% static "images/im3.jpg" %}" />
</div>
```

But this is of course not an option for 15k+ images. I thought of using jQuery to change the names within a function.

For example:

```
<div id="imageholder">
</div>
<script>   
    names = ['im1','im2','im3']
    for (i = 0; i < names.length; i++) { 
        html = `<img src="{% static "images/${names[i]}" %}" />`
        $('#imageholder').append(html)
    }
</script>
```

I believe this would work, yet it requires me to have a list of all the names which I do not have. I thought maybe I could use `os.listdir()` but I wouldn't know how to get that into the webpage.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your view add the list to a context:

```
images = os.listdir("path/to/images") #Can use glob as well
context = {'images': images}
return render(request,'/path/to/template',context}
```

In the template:

```
{% for image in images %}
     {% with 'path/to/imagedir/'|add:image as imagePath %}
     <img src='{% static imagePath %}' />
     {% endwith %}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1):

You may pregenerate iterable of `images/imN.jpg` strings in your context, and iterate over it in template.

```
class MyView(TemplateView):
    ...
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        ctx = super(MyView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        ctx['names'] = ('images/im{}.jpg'.format(i) for i in range(100))
        return ctx
    ...
```

```
<div id="imageholder">
{% for name in names %}
    <img src="{% static name %}" />
{% endfor %}
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

in the particular view function from where you want to send the images to template

```
import os 
images = os.listdir('/path_to_static')
return render(request,'template.html',{'images':images})
```

In the template:

```
{% for img in images %}
<img src="{% static 'img' %}">
{% endfor %}
```